# I need to use Mongoose to search with non-overlapping parameters?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I need some help using `Model.find()` in Mongoose.

I’ve added a boolean field isPrivate to a data model so users can specify if they want their entries to be publicly viewable, or viewable only by them.  Here’s the current index function which returns all documents:

```
  Snippet.find({})
    .populate('addedBy')
    .then(snippets => res.json(snippets))
    .catch(err => {res.json(err)})
}
```

I need to modify this so that it returns all documents where `isPrivate === false` AND all documents where `isPrivate === true` if the current user ID matches the document’s field that logged the user ID when created.  Any ideas?  Making either of these queries is simple, but I need to make both of them.

1. I’m not sure how to use Model.find() with two sets of parameters.  Is this possible?
2. Or is there a way to make two Mongoose queries and combine the results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your requirements are, using the [$or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) should help:

```
Snippet.find({
   $or: [
     {isPrivate: false}, 
     {isPrivate: true, creatorField: currentUserId} 
   ] 
 }) 
 .populate('addedBy') 
 .then(snippets => res.json(snippets)) 
 .catch(err => {res.json(err)}) }
```

This will return all documents where isPrivate is false, as well as all documents where isPrivate is true and the creator is the current user. (you'll of course have to adapt `creatorField` and `currentUserId`)

If however, you want to query on the populated field addedBy, you'll have to use the aggregation framework with the $lookup operator.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't gotten a chance to test this yet but within minutes of your post someone sent me the same solution on Slack so I think it's going to accomplish what I need.